# What Jar file do i need to download for my finch project (java)

Tags: java, finch

This might seem like a trivial question but it's really confusing.

So I need to add a jar file to my project related to programming a finch as it shows errors such as 'finch cannot be resolved' etc even though I imported the package. But which specific JAR file do I need to download because I don't seem to have it on my own PC.

So the steps are: Project>properties>build path>Add external jars > (which file??)

Thank you.

Edit: this is the site I've been directed to for downloading the file https://github.com/CMU-CREATE-Lab/finch

Comment: so you use something in your "project" and you don't know what it is? So why not post your code here and the line that the compiler is objecting to?

Comment: You have to dowmload the .jar file [here](http://www.finchrobot.com/sites/default/files/Windows/FinchJava.zip), unzip it and then add it to your project.

Comment: You may try the following link: http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/f/Downloadfinchcorejar.htm

Comment: by adding you mean going to build path and adding an external jar right? i added that file but still get syntax errors next to    Finch myfinch = new Finch();

Comment: ok i worked it out thanks guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are talking about the finch robot,
you need to download jar from their site

http://www.finchrobot.com/software/processing

as per your OS 
and then paste it in your projects folder 
after that add it to the build path of your project.